# H alpha - double peak (Be star)

Tags: spectroscopy, spectra, stellar-astrophysics, h-alpha

What is the double peak in this case, please? What does the third mean? Many thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: There's hyperfine splitting and isotope differences (protons vs deuterium) http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/hydfin.html  btw are these wavelengths reported for air or corrected for vacuum wavelength?

Comment: Thank you. So, 656.47 nm is the wavelength for H alpha? I am measuring V/R ratio. V is the third from the left and R the right one that is much lower? HOw can I find out whether these wavelengths are reported for air or corrected for vacuum wavelength? It is measured with a step of 0.03 A.

Comment: Whether it's corrected for vacuum or measured in air would depend on your source. The source of the data should tell you which it is and I don't think anyone here could help you figure that out without a lot more information about what your source is.

Comment: OK. Thank you for your explanation.